# ExtJs - Edit Grid cell by click on respective image in row

Tags: extjs

I am using `Ext.grid.Panel`. Now my requirement is I want to Edit particular cell by click image/button from each row which actioncolumn(xtype) and not in click on cell,

I have tried this by using rowEditing plugin but I don't want update and cancel button when cell is editing. Can I edit 2 or 3 cell out of 6 cell in grid row by clicking button / image in each row?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you only want to edit 2 or 3 out of 6 columns, you can do that with RowEditing plugin. All you have to do is, do not define "editor" property for those columns which you do not wish to be editable.

If your problem is that you do not want the update/cancel buttons, you can go for cellEditing plugin.. It works just like rowEditing plugin.. The only difference is with row editing you edit entire row at once, with cell editing you edit a cell at a time and you wont see the update/cancel buttons with cellediting